# C# > Convert string to double when input=""

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I would like to convert a string to double (very basic question isn't it ?)

```
string input = "45.00000";
double numberd = Double.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

=> my code works and I am very happy.

However I may have the following

```
string input = "";
double numberd = Double.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In this case my code does not work and I get a Exception error ;(
I wonder how I can manage such situation. Ideally when I get this I would like to have my variable **numberd** equal to null.

Can anyone help me ? 
Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Double` for parsing, but a `Double?` for storing the value, perhaps?

```
Double number;
string input = ""; // just for demo purpose, naturally ;o)
Double? nullableNumber = 
    Double.TryParse(input, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number) 
    ? (Double?)number 
    : null;

// use nullableNumber
```

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft recommends using the [Tester-Doer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009.aspx) pattern as follows:

```
string input = "";
double numberd;
if( Double.TryParse(input, out numberd) )
{
    // number parsed!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primitive types like `double` cannot be null.  You can have a nullable version with `double?` but, `Double.Parse` does not return a `double?` (just a plain `double`).

You could use [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) and check the return condition and set a `double?` to null accordingly if that would suit better.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just catch the exception and set your variable?

```
double numberd;
try {
  numberd = Double.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
} catch (System.FormatException e)
  numberd = 0.0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `Double.TryParse`

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement comparing strings or surround with try/catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't worried about other invalid values besides empty strings, here's a simple one-liner:

```
Double? numberd = (input.Length == 0) ? null : (Double?)Double.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

mzabsky was on the right path, however his solution won't build and you shouldn't hard-code empty string - it's better to check the length of a string.

Answer (score 0):

How about

`Double? numberd = String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? null : Double.Parse(str)`

In my application, I am parsing CSV files and I want these empty strings to be zero so I return 0.0 instead of null and it's all good.

*5 more*

Comment: You would have to guarantee that `str` is a number, since `String.IsNullOrEmpty("word")` returns false, causing `Double.Parse(str)` to fail. `Double.TryParse` would be a better choice since it returns a boolean whether it succeeded.

Comment: Good catch except you can't use Double.TryParse in the ternary